# Regex to remove URLS from text

Tags: java, regex

My text contains looks like this:

`"\n                The Red Hot Chili Peppers are a <ahref=\"http://www.last.fm/tag/funk%20rock\" class=\"bbcode_tag\" rel=\"tag\">funk rock</a> band based in Hollywood, California and were formed in 1983, in Los Angeles, California. The band currently consists of founding members <a href=\"http://www.last.fm/music/Anthony+Kiedis\" class=\"bbcode_artist\">Anthony Kiedis</a> (vocals) and Michael &quot;Flea&quot; Balzary (bass) along with a longtime member Chad Smith (drums). Guitarist John Frusciante quietly left the band on good terms in late 2008. 
On January 2, 2010, Josh Klinghoffer was announced as Frusciante's replacement.  \n\n

<a href=\"http://www.last.fm/music/Red+Hot+Chili+Peppers\">Read more about Red Hot Chili Peppers on Last.fm</a>.\n    \n    "`

I want to replace all the `<ahref=\"http://www.alltheUrls</a>` and the random `\n` and have this:

`"The Red Hot Chili Peppers are a funk rock band based in Hollywood, California and were formed in 1983, in Los Angeles, California. The band currently consists of founding members 
Anthony Kiedis (vocals) and Michael Flea Balzary (bass) along with a longtime member Chad Smith (drums). Guitarist John Frusciante quietly left the band on good terms in late 2008. On January 2, 2010, Josh Klinghoffer was announced as Frusciante's replacement. Read more about Red Hot Chili Peppers on Last.fm."`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://www.last.fm/legal/terms - bullet 3 might apply here.

Comment: I have an API key with them. I'm parsing this data for a school project, not for commercial purposes.

Comment: Be aware that turning HTML into plain text is more than just removing the tags.  For instance: `Tickets are nearly sold out for all of this year&rsquo;s Crosby, Stills &amp; Nash concerts.`